# Downloaded .csv file contains Type HTML Document

Tags: php, cakephp, export-to-csv

i am having problem when downloading file using Php script, Problem is when csv generated it contains document type HTML.
**"Which is: HTML document (5.9 KB)"**
I tried everything like changes Content type etc but issue still persist.
Please suggest,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide the code you're using?

Comment: Use https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-csvview and an URL with csv extension: `/foo/bar.csv`.

Comment: Thanks guys, its done